# Multiple AJAX calls in one page in React and Redux

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, redux

I am trying to create something like a front page of new websites where you get data of multiple categories.

My component structures looks like this:

MainContainer
--TopContainer
--MiddleContainer
--BottomContainer

Each container has different structures, and in MainContainer, I am making AJAX calls like this:

```
class MainContainer extends React.Component {
   componentDidMount(){
      this.props.fetchPopularArticles();
      this.props.fetchRecentArticles();
      this.props.fetchCategory1Articles();
      this.props.fetchCategory2Articles();
   }
   render() {
       const {popular, recent, category1, category2} = this.props;
       return (
          <div id="mainContent">
             <TopContainer popular={popular} recent={recent}/>
             <MiddleContainer category1={category1}/>
             <BottomContainer category2={category2}/>
          </div>
       );
    }
```

All data is fetched without any problem, but in the browser, every component gets the same props or data that fetched last. so data I see in the browser are all the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Something might be wrong with the reducers. Reducers hold immutable state. State changes should be copied over to a new object. Also, sharing your container code will be helpful, especially the function which connects the reducers.

Comment: @vijayst yep. I was using the same type/case for everything lol. I jus figured it out. Thanks for your comment!